# what font is used in this image

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, fonts

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW54b.png)

It looks like "DejaVu Sans Mono" or "Menlo", but after comparing the "i" letter, it should be neither of these two fonts.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could tell me its name, thx.

Comment: font `Source Code Pro`

Comment: Thanks @rioV8, after comparison, it is indeed the most similar to this font, although it still looks a little different from the image on my computer, I don’t know if it is because of the screen of the MacBook I use.

Answer (score 0):

The font for the entire image is Segoe UI. Remember this. ;)